# Figure out compulsory field to create object rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I am wondering if there is a command which will tell you which fields you need to fill in, in order to create an object>

Example:

I have a `User(name, password, email, zip code)` table,
With the following validations:

`validates :name, :password, :email, presence: true`

In order to use : `User.create`, I have to give it a name, password and email to succeed.

Since I have some tables with more than 20 fields and I don't want to check the validations every time I create an object, is there a command(to use on rails console), which lists all the fields that need to be present?

Comment: I guess there is nothing, but calling `.save!` on object will raise validation errors for you if any particular field is not validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [validators method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validators) for 'PresenceValidator'.

With a model like this:

```
class Commentary < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :match

  validates_presence_of :content, :match_id
end
```

When you do:

```
 Commentary.validators
    .select { |validation| validation.to_s.include?('PresenceValidator') }
    .map{|validation| validation.attributes }
    .flatten
```

you get:

```
[:content, :match_id]
```

Those are your compulsory fields to be provided on create of ActiveModel.